# Prism Xamarin.Forms dependency injection constructor parameters

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with Prism. I'm using the Dependency Injection provided by prism. (also to inject instances of my own classes, not only platform specific)

My question is how can I pass parameters to the constructor in Dependency Injection?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally don't pass parameters via a ctor.  You only inject your class dependencies such as services.  To inject your services just register them with the container in the RegisterTypes method in the App.cs

Assuming you are using Unity:

`Container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(optionally make it a singleton)`